# Fullcalendar drag event outside of agendaWeek / agendaDay in trash can

Tags: drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

i'm trying to add a trash can into my fullcalendar plugin like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33338943/fc/index.html

This works fine with the "month" view and the basics views. If i'm trying to do this with the agendaViews, the event is not dragable outside of the calendar. So I can't drop it onto the trash can. It does work, but it is "behind" it.

Does anyone know how to fix it, that the event is visible and dragable out of the calendar view?

Answer (score 3):

Within the Agenda Views, the DIV where each event resides has *Overflow* set to *hidden* or *auto*.

You can test the theory, by adding the following to **fullcalendar.css**;

```
.fc-view div {
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

However, a side-effect of doing this is that all views will render at full height.

Not a solution... but it may point you in the right direction?